# Android heart animation

Tags: android, canvas, imageview, android-canvas

I'm trying to make a time animation in a heart:
I have a heart-image and the background of my heart should be filled. But it's important, that I can handle the fill level of the heart. So if my time is full, the background in the heart is full, is my time empty, the background is also empty..

I thought, that I can use a image view with the heart, which lay on the view, which show the fill level, but this doesn't work, because of the heart-form. At this moment I think, I have to use canvas to draw the heart with the background. But is there any other solutions?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You can use a png-image where the heart-shape is transparent, then behind it just draw a rectangle located at the bottom of the image and let it grow in height as the time goes.

Comment: I think this will not work, because the heart is thin at the bottom and will be bigger

Comment: @user3621165 Here's an example in javascript http://jsfiddle.net/5yzzeLqq/. I couldn't find a heart that was transparent in the middle but you get the idea, right?